# oath2 - Authorization Code Grant with Flask (accessing bitbucket)?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm testing various `oath2` workflows and the one I'm strugglink to, is `Authorization Code Grant`.

I can successfully get a token If I copy/paste urls in a straight forward way.

I mean `request access`, `copy paste given URl`, `enter it in a browser`, `accept authorization`, `copy paste back callback url` -> **access resources**. Like in this example:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session


class ClientSecrets:
    """
    The structure of this class follows Google convention for `client_secrets.json`:
    https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
    Bitbucket does not emit this structure so it must be manually constructed.
    """
    client_id = "myid"
    client_secret = "mysecret"
    auth_uri = "https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize"
    token_uri = "https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token"
    server_base_uri = "https://api.bitbucket.org/"


def main():
    c = ClientSecrets()
    # Fetch a request token
    bitbucket = OAuth2Session(c.client_id)
    # Redirect user to Bitbucket for authorization
    authorization_url = bitbucket.authorization_url(c.auth_uri)
    print('Please go here and authorize: {}'.format(authorization_url[0]))
    # Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
    redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')
    # Fetch the access token
    bitbucket.fetch_token(
      c.token_uri,
      authorization_response=redirect_response,
      username=c.client_id,
      password=c.client_secret)
    # Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
    r = bitbucket.get(c.server_base_uri + '1.0/user')
    print(r.content)
```

Though if I try to do that using Flask imitating actual web app that tries to get access to bitbucket, it fails to get access.

My Flask app implementation sample looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, session

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

app = Flask(__name__)

client_id = 'myid'
client_secret = 'mysecret'
authorization_base_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize'
token_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token'
redirect_uri = 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/callback'


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    oauth2 = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
    authorization_url, state = oauth2.authorization_url(
        authorization_base_url,

    )
    # State is used to prevent CSRF, keep this for later.
    session['oauth_state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    bitbucket = OAuth2Session(client_id, state=session['oauth_state'])
    bitbucket.fetch_token(
        token_url,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        authorization_response=request.url)
    return bitbucket.get('some_resource_url').content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Certificate and key files.
    context = ('cert/server.crt', 'cert/server.key')
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

If I run app like in example, then I get this error when trying to access URL: `https://127.0.0.1:5000/login`

```
File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/test.py", line 23, in login
    session['oauth_state'] = state
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 350, in __setitem__
    self._get_current_object()[key] = value
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 130, in _fail
    raise RuntimeError('The session is unavailable because no secret '
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

It looks like that something todo with `oath_state`. If I comment `oath_state` assigning and try to run app like before. Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/test.py", line 33, in callback
    authorization_response=request.url)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 244, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 409, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 376, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 383, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
  File "/home/oerp/python-programs/flask-app/bitiface/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/errors.py", line 325, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) redirect_uri does not match
```

It looks like if I skip `oath_session`, then it actually starts new session on callback and redirect_uri will not match or something like that.

**Does anyone know what could be the problem?**

**Update**

I updated Flask with `secret_key`, so error regarding no `secret_key` is gone, but the second error is still there. This error: `InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) redirect_uri does not match` is raised at this part of code:

```
...
...
bitbucket.fetch_token(
    token_url,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    authorization_response=request.url)
...
...
```

I do not know if this is related, but printing `request.url`, it gives me this: `https://127.0.0.1:5000/callback?state=[bunch_of_random_symbols]`. So the first part `https://127.0.0.1:5000/callback` is exactly the same as I I set on consumer to be callback URL. To me it looks like it is actually matching.
`

P.S. Full traceback is provided.

Comment: 1. First you need to set a session [secret key](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions) in order to use Flask sessions. 2. Could you extend the last traceback? What line of code has caused this error?

Comment: @SergeyShubin look in updated question. I have answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the main error is `redirect_uri` argument which is present in authorization URL but not passed in access token request. As [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) describes:

> redirect_uri
>
> REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and their values MUST be identical.

So you need to initialize your callback OAuth session with `redirect_uri`:

```
@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    bitbucket = OAuth2Session(
        client_id, state=session['oauth_state'], redirect_uri=redirect_uri
    )
```

It is rather common question among developers why we need to send `redirect_uri` for getting access token. [This discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44214/what-is-the-purpose-of-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-checking) on Security.Stackexchange could be helpful.

As for the first error:

```
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

It is raised when you try to save some information in Flask session but [secret key](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions) for Flask application was not set.